# SEVERE: org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my Entity class I have the following, calling a oracle function which returns sys_refcursor

```
    @Entity
    @javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "getEmp", 
    query = "{ ? = call getemployees }", resultClass = Employees.class, hints = {
    @javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
    @Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
    public class Employees {
```

and in DAO I have

```
@Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Employees> getEmployees() {

        List query = new ArrayList<Employees>();
         try{
         query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .getNamedQuery("getEmp").list();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("exception "+e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return query;
    }
```

But when I run my application I am getting the following exception

> exception Named query not known: getEmp
>       SEVERE: org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: getEmp
>           at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:149)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:1257)
>           at net.test.employees.dao.EmployeesDAO.getEmployees(EmployeesDAO.java:34)
>           at net.test.employees.service.EmployeesService.getEmployees(EmployeesService.java:24)

How can I resolve this issue? Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by adding the following in **applicationContext.xml**.

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">  
          <list>
           <value>net.test.model.Employees</value>
           </list>  
           </property>
```